# Bitbucket credentials in url

Tags: git, azure, authentication, bitbucket

I have the situation that i want to do a pull from bitbucket from azure.
This repo is a private one so someway i have to specify credentials.

So i want to try something like this: https://username:password@bitbucket.org/mycompany/myrep.git

Does someone know or this might work? Or do i maybe have to make use of some SSH construction? I make use of Kudu ARM templates, where you can specify the repository and the branch, but so far i did not find a way to specify the credentials.

Comment: Added an answer, you were right from the beginning looks like

Answer (score 0):

For bitbucket you can use credential caching

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout 3600'
```

Follow this [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/permanently-authenticating-with-git-repositories-776639846.html)

for more information .

Comment: Well the problem is that i have to store the url in a JSON, so i really need to store it into the url somewhere, so your solution is not really an option for me.

Comment: I think you can run this command on your azure server . so whenever you run git pull push it don't ask for credential or use ssh

Comment: If you run this command directly on server and manually perform git push pull operation for 1 time and fill credential then it will remember your credential after that you can run git command without authentication through script

Answer (score -2):

This answer should work:
[How to add credentials to Docker ADD command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56284902/how-to-add-credentials-to-docker-add-command/56285198#56285198)

---

Should just be as simple as:

```
ARG bitbucket_pwd
ARG commit

ADD "https://user@domain.com:$bitbucket_pwd@bitbucket.org/teros/vana/raw/$commit/mw/requirements.txt"  '/temp/requirements.txt'
```

---

you can pass the ARGs in using `--build-arg`

```
docker build --build-arg bitbucket_pwd="$bitbucket_password"
```