# How to add credentials to Docker ADD command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have this:

```
ADD https://bitbucket.org/teros/vana/raw/"$commit"/mw/requirements.txt  'requirements.txt'
```

---

but the HTTP request won't work since I need creds. I do know that this curl command works:

```
bitbucket_curl(){
   curl -H 'Authorization:Basic YW1bGx..plM2JyKg==' "https://api.bitbucket.org$@"
}
```

---

(token was modified, but the command is o/w right)

So maybe there's a token I can included as a url parameter with Bitbucket?

Comment: Remember that anyone who has the image can run `docker history` and get the original commands out, and therefore can easily retrieve your username and password.

Answer (score 3):

Should just be as simple as:

```
ARG bitbucket_pwd
ARG commit

ADD "https://user@domain.com:$bitbucket_pwd@bitbucket.org/teros/vana/raw/$commit/mw/requirements.txt"  '/temp/requirements.txt'
```

---

you can pass the ARGs in using `--build-arg`

```
docker build --build-arg bitbucket_pwd="$bitbucket_password"
```

Comment: DANGEROUS! This solution exposes your secrets to everyone who has access to the image.

Answer (score 0):

Do neither use `--build-arg` with `ARG`/`ENV` nor `COPY` to pass secrets to your build. In both cases, the secrets can be exposed later. To not expose your secrets inside your image, you should use [Docker build secrets](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/secrets/) instead. Example for `curl`:

Build command:

```bash
export CURL_CREDS="machine bitbucket.org login MY_USERNAME password MY_PASSWORD"
docker build --secret id=curl,env=CURL_CREDS .
```

Docker command:

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=curl \
    curl -o /temp/requirements.txt --netrc-file /run/secrets/curl https://bitbucket.org/teros/vana/raw/$commit/mw/requirements.txt
```